# Query by object property in child array

Tags: postgresql

I have jsonb documents in Postgres table like this:

```json
{
  "Id": "267f9e75-efb8-4331-8220-932b023b3a34",
  "Name": "Some File",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "supplier",
      "Value": "70074"
    },
    {
      "Key": "customer",
      "Value": "1008726"
    }
  ]
}
```

My working query to find documents where `Tags.Key` is `supplier` is this:

```sql
FROM docs
    WHERE EXISTS(
      SELECT TRUE
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'Tags') x
      WHERE x ->> 'Key' IN ('supplier')
```

I wanted to find a shorter way and tried this:

```sql
select * from docs where data->'Tags' @> '[{ "Key":"supplier"}]';
```

But then I get this error for the syntax of `@>`:

```
<operator>, AT, EXCEPT, FETCH, FOR, GROUP, HAVING, INTERSECT, ISNULL, LIMIT, NOTNULL, OFFSET, OPERATOR, ORDER, TIME, UNION, WINDOW, WITH or '[' expected, got '@'
```

My questions are: is there a shorter working query and what's wrong with my second query?

Comment: The second query [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/0GHcVC9c)

Comment: Indeed. Looks like it's an IDE issue. Thanks!

Comment: Note you can write this a bit shorter using `data @> '{"Tags": [{ "Key":"supplier"}]}';`

Answer (score 0):

It's actually been an IDE issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-83829/Postgres-json-query-error-but-works-in-DataGrip